# Project price of publicly traded contract

Tags: c#, mathematics

I have to project the price for a publicly traded contract when the price should be approximately matching the targeted profit or loss. I have written the following code, runs under 0.02ms.. could be a faster and could be a bit more elegant as the code will get slower progressively depending on the iterations needed. I have documented the code, hope that it makes sense.

```
class Contract
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public decimal CommisionPerTrade { get; set; }
    public decimal MinTick { get; set; }
    public string PriceFormat { get; set; }

    private (int pos, decimal avgCost) position;

    public void AssignPossition(int shares, decimal averagePrice)
    {
        position = (shares, averagePrice);
    }

    public (int pos, decimal avgCost) Position => position;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get an exchange acceptable price for a contract for a given Profit & Loss value.
    /// The price depends on the rounding of a given contract, possible minimum - ticks are 100, 10, 1.0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0005
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pnl">The P&L that is aimed for.</param>
    /// <param name="mayBeHigher">if set to <c>true</c> then loss may be higher as well as profit to take the next acceptable 
    /// contract price else accept less rather them more.</param>
    /// <returns>a acceptable price at a given Min-Tick range that would get a approximate P&L</returns>
    /// <remarks>Please note that loss is a negative number, loss may be higher is actually a lower number as a loss of -100 is 
    /// higher than a loss of -50</remarks> 
    public bool TryGetPriceAtPnl(decimal pnl, bool mayBeHigher, out double price)
    {

        if ((Math.Abs(pnl) <= CommisionPerTrade && mayBeHigher == false)

            || (Position.avgCost == 0 || Position.pos == 0))
        {
            price = 0;
            return false;
        }


        //the current price paid for the contract
        decimal priceAtPnl = Position.avgCost;

        //start with deducting the commission that will need to be paid
        decimal sum = -CommisionPerTrade;

        //get the Price for minimal price change (min-tick) in the current position on a contract
        //positions when short contain negative values so best to take abs values
        decimal pnlPerTick = (Math.Abs(Position.pos) * (Position.avgCost + MinTick))
                            - (Math.Abs(Position.pos) * Position.avgCost);

        if (position.pos > 0)// long trade
        {

            if (pnl > 0) //profit target
            {
                //positive P&L 
                while ((!mayBeHigher && sum + pnlPerTick <= pnl) || (mayBeHigher && sum <= pnl))
                {
                    sum += pnlPerTick;
                    priceAtPnl += MinTick;//next allowed price by adding the minimum price change
                }
            }
            else //loss target
            {
                //when a negative P&L "may be higher" then this actually is, and must be, a lower value
                while ((!mayBeHigher && sum - pnlPerTick >= pnl) || (mayBeHigher && sum >= pnl))
                {
                    sum -= pnlPerTick;
                    priceAtPnl -= MinTick;//previous allowed price by subtracting the minimum price change
                }
            }
        }
        else // short trade
        {
            if (pnl > 0) //profit target
            {
                //positive P&L 
                while ((!mayBeHigher && sum + pnlPerTick >= pnl) || (mayBeHigher && sum >= pnl))
                {
                    sum += pnlPerTick;
                    priceAtPnl -= MinTick;//next allowed price by adding the minimum price change
                }
            }
            else //loss target
            {
                //when a negative P&L "may be higher" then this actually is, and must be, a lower value
                while ((!mayBeHigher && sum - pnlPerTick >= pnl) || (mayBeHigher && sum >= pnl))
                {
                    sum -= pnlPerTick;
                    priceAtPnl += MinTick;//previous allowed price by subtracting the minimum price change
                }
            }


        }

        //can't have floating point imprecision but need to return a double so cast the decimal to a double
        price = Convert.ToDouble(priceAtPnl);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have several unit tests and all look to be projecting the correct price for both long and short trades as well as profit targets and stop-loss prices.

Here are 2 unit tests

```
public void NativeTrainerTestPriceAtPnlGoodCaseShortLoss()
{

    var contract = new Contract() { Symbol = "ABC", Currency = "ABC", CommisionPerTrade = 238.50M + 238.48M, MinTick = 0.001M, PriceFormat = "N2" };
    contract.AssignPossition(shares: -100_000, averagePrice: 118.891M);

    /* P&L table for short trades
        * ______________________________________
        * PRICE       P&L       Min-Ticks
        * 118.901    -1476.98    10           P
        * 118.900    -1376.98    9            R
        * 118.899    -1276.98    8            I
        * 118.898    -1176.98    7            C
        * 118.897    -1076.98    6            E
        * 118.896     -976.98    5            
        * 118.895     -876.98    4            U
        * 118.894     -776.98    3            P
        * 118.893     -676.98    2
        * 118.892     -576.98    1
        * 118.891     -476.98    0  ---      BASE PRICE
        * 118.890     -376.98    1
        * 118.889     -276.98    2           P
        * 118.888     -276.98    3           R
        * 118.887     -176.98    4           I
        * 118.886      -76.98    5           C
        * 118.885       23.02    6           E
        * 118.884      123.02    7
        * 118.883      223.02    8           D
        * 118.882      323.02    9           O
        * 118.881      423.02    10          W
        * 118.880      523.02    11          N
        */


    //warm up .net to make sure we are jitted
    contract.TryGetPriceAtPnl(700, false, out double _);

    var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Assert.IsTrue(contract.TryGetPriceAtPnl(pnl: -700.00M, mayBeHigher: false, out double price), "Calculate price for P&L 700 must be possible, however returned false");
    sw.Stop();



    Assert.IsTrue(price > 0, "Price must always be more then 0");
    Assert.AreEqual(118.893D, price);
    if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0.02)
        Assert.Inconclusive($"Non Functional requirement, price calculations must be under 2 ms, this server did it in {sw.Elapsed}");


}
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Trade Stop-Loss")]        
public void NativeTrainerTestPriceAtPnlGoodCaseLongLoss()
{

    /* P&L table for long trades
        * ______________________________________
        * PRICE       P&L       Min-Ticks
        * 118.936      523.12   10          
        * 118.935      423.12    9           
        * 118.934      323.12    8           
        * 118.933      223.12    7           
        * 118.932      123.12    6           
        * 118.931       23.12    5           
        * 118.930     - 76.88    4           
        * 118.929     -176.88    3           
        * 118.928     -276.88    2
        * 118.927     -376.88    1
        * 118.926     -476.88    0  ---      
        * 118.925     -576.88    1
        * 118.924     -676.88    2           
        * 118.923     -767.88    3           
        * 118.922     -867.88    4           
        * 118.921     -967.88    5           

        */


    var contract = new Contract() { Symbol = "ABC", Currency = "ABC", CommisionPerTrade = 238.43M + 238.45M, MinTick = 0.001M, PriceFormat = "N2" };
    contract.AssignPossition(shares: 100_000, averagePrice: 118.926M);

    //warm up .net to make sure we are jitted
    contract.TryGetPriceAtPnl(700, false, out double _);

    var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();            
    contract.TryGetPriceAtPnl(pnl: -700M, mayBeHigher: false, out double price);
    sw.Stop();
    Assert.AreEqual(118.924D, price);

    contract.TryGetPriceAtPnl(pnl: -700M, mayBeHigher: true, out price);
    Assert.AreEqual(118.923D, price);

    if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0.02)
        Assert.Inconclusive($"Non Functional requirement, price calculations must be under 2 ms, this server did it in {sw.Elapsed}");


}
```

Ideally I would like to project the price without the loops. Important is that one must project valid prices as else the exchange will reject the order.

Comment: @dfhwze, yes, looks like I can

Comment: Since the method isn't pure and uses a lot of properties or other class members, I'm changing my mind about this question and vote-to-close it for the lack of context. You should add the entire class.

Comment: @t3chb0t, added the relevant properties of the class and the class. the entire class is to big to include

Comment: Great! Before I'm ready to flip my votes I need ask one more question: have you just removed irrelevant parts because it's a god-class with too many responsibilities or have also edited the code and it's different from the actual one?

Comment: @t3chb0t, the contract does quite a lot of things, a lot of them are not relevant to the issue I'm trying to solve. I am looping to get to the price that would reflect a Profit Or loss value. The other properties and methods are not referenced and only add "smoke and mirrors" to the posting. The parts that are in the contract class are 1-1 reflecting production code

Comment: Your question is still off-topic because it explicitly requests rewriting loops as something different.

Comment: Just a tip for this kind of refactoring. Put the code away and head to the whiteboard. Draw some graphs. Explore the relationship the numbers have to each other. The hard part is figuring out how to express the solution as a single equation that can calculate the solution *directly at any given point*. Sometimes you just need to stare at it for a while before the right bit of math jumps out at you. Drawings and graphs can help this process immensely.

Comment: For context, it recently took me several days of this to realize I needed the formula for a parabola in some of my code. Once I had that realization I had the code done in 20 min, but it took 2 days to have that realization to begin with.

Comment: @RubberDuck, You are spot on. Found the issue when playing in excel. now from 0.02MS to 0.0088MS for something called a "billion times"...

Comment: Can't write the solution as the refactoring apparently is an off topic. but it basicaly comes down to: var minTicksToMove = (pnl - (0- CommisionPerTrade)) / pnlPerTick; this needs to be rounded and if a greater loss or greater profit is possible one deeds to add or remove 1

Comment: I have no idea why this was closed. The code works as intended. I’ve voted to reopen it so you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks's @RubberDuck

After playing a bit in excel I have found the following solution using math and removing the loops, here you see the method, the Contract class that hosts this method for those that would like to try is above.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get an exchange acceptable price for a contract for a given Profit & Loss value.
/// The price depends on the rounding of a given contract, possible minimum - ticks are 100, 10, 1.0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0005
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pnl">The P&L that is aimed for.</param>
/// <param name="mayBeHigher">if set to <c>true</c> then loss may be higher as well as profit to take the next acceptable 
/// contract price else accept less rather them more.</param>
/// <returns>a acceptable price at a given Min-Tick range that would get a approximate P&L</returns>
/// <remarks>Please note that loss is a negative number, loss may be higher is actually a lower number as a loss of -100 is 
/// higher than a loss of -50</remarks> 
public bool TryGetPriceAtPnl(decimal pnl, bool mayBeHigher, out double price)
{

    if ((Math.Abs(pnl) <= CommisionPerTrade && !mayBeHigher) || (Position.avgCost == 0 || Position.pos == 0))
    {
        price = 0;
        return false;
    }


    //get the Price for minimal price change (min-tick) in the current position on a contract
    //positions when short contain negative values so best to take abs values
    decimal pnlPerTick =Position.pos * MinTick;

    //calculate the distance in MinTicks that one needs to go for;
    var minTicksToMove = (pnl - (0- CommisionPerTrade)) / pnlPerTick;

    if (mayBeHigher && Math.Abs(minTicksToMove) > (int)Math.Abs(minTicksToMove))
    {
        if (pnl > 0)//positive Number then MinTicksMove will be up
            minTicksToMove = (int)minTicksToMove + 1;
        else//MinTicksMove will needs to go down to allow greater loss
            minTicksToMove = (int)minTicksToMove - 1;
    }

    //can't have floating point imprecision but need to return a double so cast the decimal to a double
    price = Convert.ToDouble(Position.avgCost+((int)minTicksToMove*MinTick));
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Some observations and guidelines to get you started refactoring the code.</sub>

#### Check condition

Checking a condition against a bool is rarely written like this in C#:

> ```
> mayBeHigher == false
> ```

Prefer:

```
!mayBeHigher
```

---

#### Refactor variables to allow DRY code

If you want to get rid of those if-statements with almost identical bodies, you should refactor your code in a way a single body would suffice.

For instance, you sometimes call `sum += pnlPerTick;` other times `sum -= pnlPerTick;`. The same occurs with `priceAtPnl += MinTick;` and `priceAtPnl -= MinTick;`. Ideally, you would want to do something like this:

```
sum += offset;
priceAtPnl += priceDelta;
```

With `offset` calculated from `pnlPerTick` and `priceDelta` from `MinTick` given your parameters `position.pos` and `pnl`.

---

#### Refactor conditions for compactness

The pattern of the conditions inside the if-statements could also be written in a more compact matter. The pattern is `(!a && x + n <= k) || (a && x <= k)` which could be rewritten as `x + (!a ? n : 0) <= k`.

For instance,

> ```
> while ((!mayBeHigher && sum + pnlPerTick <= pnl) || (mayBeHigher && sum <= pnl))
> ```

Could be rewritten as:

```
while (sum + (!mayBeHigher ? pnlPerTick : 0) <= pnl))
```

Or if you introduce a variable `var padding = !mayBeHigher ? pnlPerTick : 0;` to:

```
while (sum + padding <= pnl))
```

Comment: I'm still stuck with the loop, the idea is  to remove the loop altogether

Comment: Am I correct, your DRY code just adds complexity moves the logic to another location and 2 variables? DRY vs KISS.   Also your while (sum + (!mayBeHigher ? pnlPerTick : 0) <= pnl) and while (sum + (!mayBeHigher ? pnlPerTick : 0) >= pnl) respecively will fail the unit tests

Comment: PPann why do you want to remove the loop so badly? This request is btw off-topic.

Comment: If you want to remove the loop altogether, you could use multiplication and perhaps some modulo _sum += magnitude * pnlPerTick;_ and calculate magnitude to avoid the while.

Comment: @dfhwze, yes, that's the idea however I can't solve the equation without getting in troubles with the valid prices with the exchange, hence the loop  and the priceAtPnl += MinTick; and priceAtPnl -= MinTick; respectively. The MinTick changes based on the exchange, contract and underlying instrument in the contract as well as the Real-Time price and can range from 100 to 0.00005 as written in the code comments